# Rhythmbox crashes after Update to Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: rhythmbox

Since I updated to Ubuntu 16.04 two days ago, Rhythm Box always crashes after about 10 seconds into opening.

This is the terminal output:

```
(rhythmbox:7725): Gtk-WARNING **: Duplicate child name in GtkStack: Zur Wiedergabeliste hinzufügen
(rhythmbox:7725): Gtk-WARNING **: Duplicate child name in GtkStack: Zur Wiedergabeliste hinzufügen
(rhythmbox:7725): Gtk-WARNING **: Duplicate child name in GtkStack: Zur Wiedergabeliste hinzufügen
(rhythmbox:7725): Gtk-WARNING **: Duplicate child name in GtkStack: Zur Wiedergabeliste hinzufügen
(rhythmbox:7725): Gtk-WARNING **: Duplicate child name in GtkStack: Zur Wiedergabeliste hinzufügen
(rhythmbox:7725): Gtk-WARNING **: Duplicate child name in GtkStack: Zur Wiedergabeliste hinzufügen
(rhythmbox:7725): Gtk-WARNING **: Duplicate child name in GtkStack: Zur Wiedergabeliste hinzufügen
(rhythmbox:7725): Gtk-WARNING **: Duplicate child name in GtkStack: Zur Wiedergabeliste hinzufügen
(rhythmbox-metadata:7741): GStreamer-WARNING **: Trying to set string on structure field 'owner', but string is not valid UTF-8. Please file a bug.
(rhythmbox-metadata:7741): GStreamer-WARNING **: Trying to set string on structure field 'owner', but string is not valid UTF-8. Please file a bug.
(rhythmbox:7725): RhythmDB-CRITICAL **: rhythmdb_entry_get_entry_type: assertion 'entry != NULL' failed
Speicherzugriffsfehler (Speicherabzug geschrieben)
```

I miss my Rhythmbox very much. Unfortunately I don't have any computer skills and really have no idea how to fix this.